# API Platform prefix + admin

Tags: api-platform.com

I am using the current release of Api Platform https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/releases/tag/v3.0.10 and run it with docker compose.

I want to prefix the whole API with '/api'.

But the build in admin panel gives errors as soon as I prefix the api.

I added: prefix: '/api'

```
api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: '/api'
```

to my config/api_platform.yaml

And I also added '/api*' to my Caddyfile

```
@pwa expression `(
        header({'Accept': '*text/html*'})
        && !path(
           '/api*' ,'/docs*', '/graphql*', '/bundles*', '/contexts*', '/_profiler*', '/_wdt*',
            '*.json*', '*.html', '*.csv', '*.yml', '*.yaml', '*.xml'
        )
    )
    || path('/favicon.ico', '/manifest.json', '/robots.txt', '/_next*', '/sitemap*')`
```

Now I can query the api on https://localhost/api/endpoint, and I can view the docs on https://localhost/api/docs.

But when I try to use the build in admin at https://localhost/admin, it throws errors.
If I take a look into the console I see:

- 2 xhr calls to https://localhost/ which result in 404
  And
- Error: Cannot fetch API documentation:Status: 404 adminDataProvider.js:27

And after this a whole lot more errors but I think they just a result from the above.

In the network tab there are also a lot of 404 calls to "https://localhost/__nextjs_original-stack-frame?isServer=false&isEdgeServer=false....."

Could someone tell me what I am missing?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
I guess pwa doesn't know about the changed path.

So I tried setting the environment variable       NEXT_PUBLIC_ENTRYPOINT in docker-compose.yaml from http://caddy to http:caddy/api

```
pwa:
  build:
    context: ./pwa
    target: prod
  environment:
    NEXT_PUBLIC_ENTRYPOINT: http://caddy/api
```

But that doesn't worked either.

OK I managed to do it but it doesn't feel that good.

I changed my pwa/pages/admin/index.tsx

```
setDynamicAdmin(<HydraAdmin entrypoint={window.origin + '/api'}></HydraAdmin>);
```

But I think there has to be a cleaner option via docker yaml settings.
So if you know one let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my question I don't think it's the cleanest solution but a "quick" fix was to change my pwa/pages/admin/index.tsx

from

```
setDynamicAdmin(<HydraAdmin entrypoint={window.origin}></HydraAdmin>);
```

to

```
setDynamicAdmin(<HydraAdmin entrypoint={window.origin + '/api'}></HydraAdmin>);
```